# Haproxy backend server with port 80 is not working

Tags: haproxy

I am trying to set up a haproxy which points to another haproxy server(loadbalance1-service.com) internally and its working without issues

```
backend prod_auth
   balance leastconn
   option httpchk GET /auth-service/generalhealthcheck
   http-check expect string "Service is up and reachable"
   server auth-service-1 loadbalance1-service.com:8080 check
```

Above backend in haproxy.cfg file is perfectly working, but when I change the  port to 80 in backend module requests are failing with 503 error.

```
backend prod_auth
   balance leastconn
   option httpchk GET /auth-service/generalhealthcheck
   http-check expect string "Service is up and reachable"
   server auth-service-1 loadbalance1-service.com:80 check
```

Haproxy running on loadbalance1-service.com is accessible on both 80 and 8080, I can see the proxy stats of loadbalance1-service.com on both the port.

I am curious why backend module is failing on 80 and not able to find any answer online. Thanks!

Comment: On the machine or container that's running the HAProxy instance with this configuration, what is the result of `curl loadbalance1-service.com:80/auth-service/generalhealthcheck` and `curl loadbalance1-service.com:8080/auth-service/generalhealthcheck`?  Also, if you have stats enabled on HAProxy (e.g. https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.7/configuration.html#4.2-stats%20enable), what is the check_status of auth-service-1?

Comment: @mweiss _curl loadbalance1-service.com:80/auth-service/generalhealthcheck_ is failing,
_curl loadbalance1-service.com:80/auth-service/generalhealthcheck_  is working 
and check_status  is down when its 80

Comment: Ah, apologies.  Do you mean 80 fails to connect and 8080 succeeds?  If that is the case, I guess the reason for the 503 is that the server is unreachable on port 80.

Comment: thanks, that is the issue